# What does it mean for two linear transformations to agree on a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what a question on my math homework is asking. Could anybody help clarify?

If $S, T : V \to W$ are both linear transformations that agree on a basis $\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ for $V$, then $S = T$.

It is a true/false question that requires a proof/counterexample with the answer. I can't get to that part without knowing what it is asking :\

Thank you.

Comment: That means $S(v_i) = T(v_i)$ for $i=1, \cdots, n$.

Answer (score 4):

By "agree on a basis $(v_1,...,v_n)$" they mean "have the same value on each of the basis vectors $(v_1,...,v_n)$".  So, $S(v_i)=T(v_i)$ for each $v_i$ in the basis.